# To find the value on X axis corresponding to an arbitrary value of Y that doesn't contain in the list used to plot the data in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of values for redshift and have the corresponding set of values for deceleration parameter of universe. The plot is given:

[image]

Now I need the value of z accurately from the graph for q=0. I have tried many commands and they all lead to some kind of errors. Since I am not that much in python I can't even try how to rectify all those.

When I tried the command:

`z1 = interp1d(z,q,0)`

the result was:

> scipy.interpolate.interpolate.interp1d object at 0x051899F0

How can I solve this?

My code:

```
while z0<zf:' ' 
    z.append(z0)
    a.append(1/(1+z0))
    term=((1+(omega/(B-1)))*a[k]**(3*(B-1)))
    H.append(((term-(omega/(B-1)))*H02)**0.5)
    q.append(-1-((H0*term*3*(B-1)*(term-(omega/(B-1)))-0.5)/(2*H[k])))
    print '%.2f \t%.4f \t%.4f \t%.15f'%(z[k],a[k],H[k],q[k])
    k=k+1
    z0=z0+h
```

Comment: Show code where you store values for arrays `z` and `q`. And what types of `z` and `q`?

Comment: Is there anybody to help... I am new to stack overflow. I tried formatting but it doesn't work for me..

Comment: The code you have provided does not run by itself so its difficult to be certain of the real problem. For instance you did not initialize z0, zf, h or any of the other variables. Make print(z,q) and edit your post to show the result. The scipy interpolation is failing likely because the inputs are bad.

Comment: Yes...THank you very much.. How can I do that?

Comment: No. I tried the whole program. But it was a little big that I couldn't post it.

Comment: **First part::**     `from pylab import*`
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
`from scipy.interpolate import interp1d`

`fig, ax =subplots()`
  `k=0`
  `omega,B,H0=0.6911,0.019921992722139001,67.74`    `z0=0` `h=0.05`

Comment: **Second Part::**  `z,a,H,q=[],[],[],[]` <pre>
`print'Value of H0, Omega and Beta:%.3f,%.4f,%.18f'%(H0,omega,B)`
`zf=input('Enter the final value of redshift:')`
`print 'Red shift  Scale factor   Hubble parameter        q value'`
`print '==========================================================='`
`while z0<zf:`

Comment: **The intented part under while::**  `z.append(z0)`
    `a.append(1/(1+z0))`
    `term=((1+(omega/(B-1)))*a[k]**(3*(B-1)))`
    `H.append(((term-(omega/(B-1)))*H0**2)**0.5)`
    `q.append(-1-((H0*term*3*(B-1)*(term-(omega/(B-1)))**-0.5)/(2*H[k])))`
    `print '%.2f    \t%.4f   \t%.4f   \t%.15f'%(z[k],a[k],H[k],q[k])`
    `k=k+1` 
    `z0=z0+h`

Comment: **The final part::**  `title('Decceleration parameter(q) versus Red shift(z) graph ')`
`xlabel('Redshift z')`
`ylabel('Decceleration parameter q')`
`z1 = interp1d(z,q,0)`
`print z1`
`plot(z,q)`
`ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')`
`ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')`
`ax.yaxis.tick_left()`
`ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')`
`ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')`
`ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()`
`show()`

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenient format...

Comment: Please anybody help me... I am over this problem for three days.

Comment: @RohitPk Your code is working now. There are a few things you must take in consideration but everything seems to be outputting fine. You were using the interp1D function incorrectly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code had some issues. I only have <kbd>Python 3</kbd> here so if you have any problem understanding something just ask (changed a bit the `print` and the `input` function parts).

You did not define the `H02` so I just stated it was equal to `H0`. Correct that if it is wrong. Here is your corrected code (see the comments for important stuff):

```
from pylab import*
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

fig, ax = subplots()
k = 0
omega, B, H0 = 0.6911, 0.019921992722139001, 67.74
H02 = H0 + 0 # You didn't specify this so I had to make up something
z0 = 0
h = 0.05

z, a, H, q = [], [], [], []
print('Value of H0, Omega and Beta:%.3f,%.4f,%.18f'%(H0, omega, B))
zf = float(input('Enter the final value of redshift:')) # Remember that this needs to output a number
print('Red shift Scale factor Hubble parameter q value') # I chose 10 in my test.
print('===========================================================')

while z0 < zf:
    z.append(z0)
    a.append(1/(1+z0))
    term=((1+(omega/(B-1)))*a[k]**(3*(B-1)))
    H.append(((term-(omega/(B-1)))*H02)**0.5)
    q.append(-1-((H0*term*3*(B-1)*(term-(omega/(B-1)))-0.5)/(2*H[k])))
    print('%.2f \t%.4f \t%.4f \t%.15f'%(z[k], a[k], H[k], q[k]))
    k = k+1
    z0 = z0+h

title('Decceleration parameter(q) versus Red shift(z) graph ')
xlabel('Redshift z')
ylabel('Decceleration parameter q')

z1 = interp1d(q, z)
print(z1(40000)) # I used a redshift parameter of 10 and 0 does not exist in the data limits so I just used 40 000.
plot(z, q)
plot([z1(40000), z1(40000)], [0, 40000], c='r')
plot([0, z1(40000)], [40000, 40000], c='r')

ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
show()
```

, and it results in this:

[image: Checking interception value in matplotlib plot]

I added the red line to show you the result of the interpolation which is made like this:

```
z1 = interp1d(q, z) # Create your function with your q (input) and z (output)
result = z1(40000) # This is checking the value of z when q=40000
```

The thing you need to remember is that `interp1D` will only be able to interpolate in the region of the data you gave. So if `q` is within `10` and `100` you cannot interpolate `q=0`.

I used a redshift of 10 (did not know what to use although the subject seemed interesting). This does not seem to affect the plot so I'm guessing something went wrong when you've put your code in here or when I tried to understand it from your comments (because your plot is different from mine). Make sure everything is as should be and just use the parts you can use to solve your problem.

Comment: Oh... First of all sorry if the mistake was made by me. That is, initially I may have posted the code under while loop with this mistake of `H02` instead of `H0**2`. That is why deceleration parameter had these big values. However the two things I had to change in the corrected code were `H02` to `H0**2` and the value of q, from 4000 to 0. That worked.... Thank you very much sir. You corrected my code with the right use of `interp1d`.

Comment: The image I obtained when I used `z1 = interp1d(z,q)` is this: [enter image description here][1] 


Where the red line showing the intercept at z=0 is not able see since it is along the y axis itself. I got a very good result. 

And when I used `z1 = interp1d(q,z)`, I got this image:[enter image description here][2]

Where again the red line showing the intercept at q=0 is not able to see since it is along the x axis itself. The result I got was really good.Thank you @armatita
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vVome.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfrSF.jpg

Comment: @RohitPk You are welcome. Images won't be parsed in comments so if it is important put it in your answer (+1) or your question (you can edit both of it). Happy to be of help. Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry. Since I am a new user I couldn't put it in my answer. I needed 10 points of reputation for that. Now I think I can. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The corrected program(Previously corrected by `@armatita` ) is: (where I put `zf=2` in the output)

```
from pylab import*
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

fig, ax = subplots()
k = 0
omega, B, H0 = 0.6911, 0.019921992722139001, 67.74
#H02 = H0 + 0 #I donot use a term H02
z0 = 0
h = 0.05

z, a, H, q = [], [], [], []
print('Value of H0, Omega and Beta:%.3f,%.4f,%.18f'%(H0, omega, B))
zf = float(input('Enter the final value of redshift:')) 
print('Red shift Scale factor Hubble parameter q value')
print('===========================================================')

while z0 < zf:
    z.append(z0)
    a.append(1/(1+z0))
    term=((1+(omega/(B-1)))*a[k]**(3*(B-1)))
    H.append(((term-(omega/(B-1)))*H0**2)**0.5)
    q.append(-1-((H0*term*3*(B-1)*(term-(omega/(B-1)))-0.5)/(2*H[k])))
    print('%.2f \t%.4f \t%.4f \t%.15f'%(z[k], a[k], H[k], q[k]))
    k = k+1
    z0 = z0+h

title('Decceleration parameter(q) versus Red shift(z) graph ')
xlabel('Redshift z')
ylabel('Decceleration parameter q')

z1 = interp1d(q, z)
print(z1(0)) 
plot(z, q)
plot([z1(0), z1(0)], [0, 0], c='r')
plot([0, z1(0)], [0, 0], c='r')

ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
show()
```

Previously corrected by @armatita